# Should a component have its parent's file name as part of its own file name?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to ask the correct way to name a component file.

I read the style guide.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/

I am wondering, if you make a directory contain some child components of specific component, should those child component names start with the parent component's name?

```
// OPTION 1:

file) ParentA.vue

directory) ParentA

 |_ file) ParentAChildA.vue
```

```
// OPTION 2

file) ParentA.vue

directory) ParentA

 |_ file) ChildA.vue
```

Which is proper?

Comment: Pick a convention and stick to it; consistency is more important.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is kind of opinion based.
Most developers use both approaches. Why?

**Example for option 1:**
Imagine a todo list from a classic todo app. First we have `TodoList` as wrapper for the items, maybe with some sorting options and so on. One item (= child component) would then be called `TodoListItem`.

**Example for option 2:**
Imagine some dashboard-style app. We have multiple shown components that aren't directly mutual (can but don't have to be). So we would have a `Dashboard` component. Of course, `DashboardItem` with dynamic values would also work but is overkill for most applications. So one would just use `Dashboard` and then `Investments` as child.

Most important: Be concise and consistent in naming your components (and of course also variables, services, etc.).

Comment: Thank you.
I am sorry, what is "So one would just use Dashboard and then Investments as child" mean?

Comment: If multiple component, I would place those on different name of directory such as "Gobals". What I want to ask is if you place "ParentAChildA.vue" in "ParentA" folder, the phrase "ParentA" would be duplicated.

Comment: Like you would not name id property  ,"personId" in class "Person". We would just name that property "id". Event though I thought maybe it is better to name "ParentAChildA.vue" because it is comprehensible. But the phrase "ParentA" is duplicated. So I was wondering which is better.

Comment: @akao as said, it really depends on the code style and occasion. :)